# Preventing Shadows from Incorrectly Casting Through Floors

Tags: three.js, shadow, react-three-fiber

I'm facing a shadow rendering issue in Three.js. I have a three-floor building model, and on the third floor, there's a car. I'm using a directional light to cast shadows. The setup is such that the car casts shadows (castShadow=true, receiveShadow=false), and the floors receive them (castShadow=false, receiveShadow=true). However, the problem arises with the shadow casting behavior. Instead of being limited to the third floor, where the car is located, the shadow also incorrectly appears on the first and second floors. This seems like a shadow leakage issue where the shadow penetrates through these floors.

How can I prevent the shadow from incorrectly casting onto the wrong floors, ensuring it only appears on the third floor directly under the car? Any advice or solutions to fix this shadow problem would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Example]

I tried layer lighting but in my case I can have more than 32 floors so this may not be a solution.

Comment: The physical problem here is that the floors should actually also cast a shadow. Anyway, you can try to limit the shadow by the distance to the "far" plane of the shadow camera.